# jQuery selector :first in class, but id :not starts with

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I need to select the first element in class, but with id not starting with certain string.

I tried :

```
$('.ai:first:not([id^="tip"])').outerHeight(true)
```

and

```
$('.ai:first').not('[id^="tip"]').outerHeight(true)
```

Nothing seems to be working properly. Please advise.

Comment: try this `:not([id='tip'])`

Comment: @Dr.Strange It will exclude any element with ID attribute

Comment: Can you provide your HTML too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery [`.eq(x)`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) method to get the `x`th element matching your selector:

```
$('.ai:not([id^="tip"])').eq(0)
```

*PS: `.eq()`'s index starts at `zero`*

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can use regex inside the :not selector but I think this should work.

$('.ai:first:not(#tip)').outerHeight(true)